# How to make a table of figures that were created with a style but not with captions? (Word 2010)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have the following figure and subtitle, that was created with a style, and therefore is not a caption i can choose to create a table of contents.

[image]

How can I choose this style or numbering order, to create a table with them?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: as far as I konw there is no specific style for figure / table captions in word, when you create table of figures it collects all the paragraphs starting with the appropriate field code (as in your picture you've already added kind of code, check it against other automatically created field codes). Doing a bit of research other common reasons causing a caption is not included in the table: use of tracked changes (try to accept all changes in the document) or use of textboxes for captions (have only plain text!).

Comment: Not really, when I choose to insert a table of figures, it will ask for a caption, take a look here: http://puu.sh/j4SQ0/8021ad3b9a.png  If i give him no caption, it wont allow me to create a list.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
What i did was going to "Edit Field", "Table of contents" to manage

[image]

and on the options button just choose a style

[image]

There it goes,just apply the replace when it askes and it will show up a list of the figures based on any style.